# Model is being a little wonky

Tags: modeling, animation

So I downloaded this model for an animation I'm making and it's really good except for one thing. When I go to move the face/head bone the ends of the ears do not follow the rotation of the head and stay in place while the lower half of the ears do follow the head. I've tried creating new bones and parented them to the pre existing ear bones (which only move half of the ear as shown in the pictures) yet even then it doesn't completely follow the rotation. I've messed around with vertex groups and using many of the pre existing bones but there I haven't yet found a solution. Down below are a before and after in turning the head of the model for a visual. Please help lol.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create new bones to fix the problem, the problem is in the vertices assignment, they belong to some vertex groups they should not be part of, select all these dysfunctional vertices, click on the down arrow button on the right ot the vertex groups list, click on *Remove from All Groups*, then assign to the group they should be part of